# How To Disable Dropdown Values if its not satisfy condition Using dynamoDB

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

**How To Disable Drop down Values if its not satisfy condition in dynamo Db AWS using Boto3 python**

**having some criteria to satisfy:**
1 if the initial value is generated then only other values enable and the initial value get disabled
2 one by one the condition get satisfied and the previous one gets disabled

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your question is very hard to understand and missing a lot of details. Please share more information with the community and share your code, what you tried so far, what is not working, possible errors and what you are trying to achieve in a more concise way. Otherwise, other community members won't be able to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.